# display a particular size within an icns file in webkit

Tags: macos, webkit, icons, titanium

On a webpage I have

```
<img src="icon/GenericFolderIcon.icns" style="height: 16px; width: 16px;">
```

However, it only displays the resized version of the 512x512 icon.

**Is there a way to display the 16x16 version without having to convert?**

I am using webkit within Titanium on osx.